# JQuery Div not animating in click function

Tags: jquery, click

I have the following code, I am attempting to have a div animate on a click event, but for some reason the div is immediately moving to the location and it's not animating to the coordinates specified, what am I doing wrong here? code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example1').click(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        $('#example1-xy').html("X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
        var leftOfShip = x;                                              
        //var leftOfShip = document.getElementById("ship").style.left + 20;
        $("#ship").animate({left: $("#ship").css("left",leftOfShip)},5000);
    });
  });
```

Any Advice would be of help!!

Answer (score 2):

You're miscalling `animate`.

Change it to

```
$("#ship").animate({ left: leftOfShip }, 5000);
```

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 0):

I think the animate function only works on the "number" parameter.

The following:

```
$("#ship").animate({left: $("#ship").css("left",leftOfShip)},5000);
```

should be:

```
$("#ship").animate({left: "500px", 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your animate call:

```
$("#ship").animate({left: $("#ship").css("left",leftOfShip)},5000);
```

needs to become:

```
$("#ship").animate({left: leftOfShip}), 5000);
```

you can play with some of the code at http://www.jsfiddle.net/7yNM4/ in a very simple mock up.